# Why does the following for loop not work in setting the element value to an integer? Why is the value after the logical operator "or" not recognized?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, logical-operators

> I'm writing a poker hand simulator, I want to convert the string
>   inputs to integers: "a" or "A" --> 1 "j" or "J" --> 11 "q" or "Q" -->
>   12 "k" or "K" --> 13
>
> ['a',7],['J',8] should output: [1, 7], [11, 8]
>
> 1. [first two for loops] - There's something about for loops that I don't seem to understand. I'm trying to use for loops with if
>      statements and logical operators to set the elements of a list to a
>      certain value if the element is equal to certain values, but the
>      original values remain unchanged when I try to do this.
> 2. [3rd and 4th loops, while loops with logical operator "or"] - The first character, before the "or" is recognized in the if statement
>      ("a" is converted to 1). But the second character, after the "or" is
>      ignored ("J" is not converted to 11).
>
> The 5th and 6th loop, without using logical operators, nor a for loop,
>   work as it should.
>
> As shown in the last two loops (5th and 6th), if I use a while loop
>   instead of a for loop AND if I don't use the logical operator "or"
>   everything works fine. But why?
>
> ```
> >def convert(p1,p2):
> >    one, two = p1[::], p2[::] # these lists are fed into the while loops 
> >                                   #with logical operators
> >
> >    this_works_1, this_works_2 = p1[::], p2[::] # these lists are fed 
> >              #into the while loops without logical operators, THEY WORK!
> >
> >    # Question 1: Why do the following 2 for loops loop work (doesn't 
> >                      # change the list elements)
> >    for x in p1:
> >        if x == ("a" or "A"):
> >            x = 1
> >        if x == ("j" or "J"):
> >            x = 11
> >        if x == ("q" or "Q"):
> >            x = 12
> >        if x == ("k" or "K"):
> >            x = 13
> >    for x in p2:
> >        if x == ("a" or "A"):
> >            x = 1
> >        if x == ("j" or "J"):
> >            x = 11
> >        if x == ("q" or "Q"):
> >            x = 12
> >        if x == ("k" or "K"):
> >            x = 13
> >
> >    #Questions 2: Why is the string after the logical operator "or" not 
> >                      # recognized - "J" is not converted to 11
> >    index = 0
> >    while index < len(one):
> >        if one[index] == ("a" or "A"):
> >            one[index] = 1
> >        if one[index] == ("j" or "J"):
> >            one[index] = 11
> >        if one[index] == ("q" or "Q"):
> >            one[index] = 12
> >        if one[index] == ("k" or "K"):
> >            one[index] = 13
> >        index += 1
> >
> >    index = 0
> >    while index < len(two):
> >        if two[index] == ("a" or "A"):
> >            two[index] = 1
> >        if two[index] == ("j" or "J"): # if I switch the order to ("J" or 
> >                    #"j"), the upper-case "J" is properly converted to 11
> >            two[index] = 11
> >        if two[index] == ("q" or "Q"):
> >            two[index] = 12
> >        if two[index] == ("k" or "K"):
> >            two[index] = 13
> >        index += 1
> >
> >    index = 0        
> >    while index < len(this_works_1):
> >        if this_works_1[index] == "a":
> >            this_works_1[index] = 1
> >        if this_works_1[index] == "A":
> >            this_works_1[index] = 1
> >        if this_works_1[index] == "j":
> >        if this_works_1[index] == "J":
> >            this_works_1[index] = 11
> >        if this_works_1[index] == "q":
> >            this_works_1[index] = 12
> >        if this_works_1[index] == "Q":
> >            this_works_1[index] = 12
> >        if this_works_1[index] == "k":
> >            this_works_1[index] = 13
> >        if this_works_1[index] == "K":
> >            this_works_1[index] = 13
> >        index += 1
> >
> >    index = 0        
> >    while index < len(this_works_2):
> >        if this_works_2[index] == "a":
> >            this_works_2[index] = 1
> >        if this_works_2[index] == "A":
> >            this_works_2[index] = 1
> >        if this_works_2[index] == "j":
> >            this_works_2[index] = 11
> >        if this_works_2[index] == "J":
> >            this_works_2[index] = 11
> >        if this_works_2[index] == "q":
> >            this_works_2[index] = 12
> >        if this_works_2[index] == "Q":
> >            this_works_2[index] = 12
> >        if this_works_2[index] == "k":
> >            this_works_2[index] = 13
> >        if this_works_2[index] == "K":
> >            this_works_2[index] = 13
> >        index += 1
> >
> >    return p1, p2, one, two, this_works_1, this_works_2
> ```
>
> ['a',7],['J',8] should output: [1, 7], [11, 8]
>
> convert(['a',7],['J',8]) should output: ([1, 7], [11, 8], [1, 7], [11,
>   8], [1, 7], [11, 8])
>
> but the actual output is: (['a', 7], ['J', 8], [1, 7], ['J', 8], [1,
>   7], [11, 8])

Comment: As a side note, any idea why I keep getting this error? (This is my first post btw)
"Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon."

Comment: This is because you are not formatting the code properly. On StackOverflow, if you want to post some code, you indent it using 4 extra spaces in the beginning or use the buttons provided in the editor.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because in the first line of the function itself you are cloning the lists `p1` and `p2` into `one` and `two` respectively.

And in the last line of the function, you are returning `p1, p2, one, two, this_works_1, this_works_2`.

In the code, you never modified the values of `p1` or `p2`. You modified the values of `one`, `two`, `this_works_1`, `this_works_2`. So, it will not directly change the values of `p1` and `p2` and will return their original values.

For example,

```
a = [0, 1]
print(a) # [0, 1]

# If you just assign variable a to some other variable b
# and then modify it, it will change the value of variable a directly
b = a
b[0] = 2
print(b) # [2, 1]
print(a) # [2, 1]

# But if you clone it, you can't change the value of original list
c = a[::]
c[0] = 3
print(c) # [3, 1]
print(a) # [2, 1]
print(b) # [2, 1]
```

See the difference?

Answer (score 0):

> # Question 1: Why do the following 2 for loops loop work (doesn't change the list elements)

When doing `for x in p1`, `x` is not a reference to the object in the list, but rather a copy because you only have `str` and `int`, which are immutable.

so when you are changing the value of `x`, you only override the *copy* of the actual object, not the object itself. Therefor, you don't see any effect on the list.

> #Questions 2: Why is the string after the logical operator "or" not recognized - "J" is not converted to 11

when doing `(obj1 or obj2)` in python, the following happens:

1. if `bool(obj1)` is `true`, then the expression becomes **obj1** (**NOT** `True`)
2. else, if `bool(obj2)` is `true`, then the expression becomes **obj2** (also here, **NOT** `True`)
3. else, the expression becomes `False`

In this case, since `bool("j")` is true (non-zero value), then `("j" or "J")` becomes `"j"` and becuase `one[index]` is `"J"` (and not `"j"), the whole expression becomes`False`, so the assignment does not execute, and the value doesn't get converted.